# Div desalinhada

Tags: css

Tenho estas duas `div`

```
<div class="widget nuvem" style="position: static">
    <h3>Nuvem de Palavras</h3>
        <div class="tags">
            <? foreach($inicial_nuvem as $valor){ ?>
            <div class="tag label btn-info">
                <span><a href="<?=base_url('/blog/categoria/'.$valor->id."/".url_title($valor->categoria))?>" style="color: white;"><? echo $valor->categoria; ?></a></span>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
       </div>
</div>

<div class="widget acervo">
    <h3>Dados de Acervo</h3>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="ultimos-artigos">Publicações: <? echo $inicial_acervo[0]->total_posts; ?></li>
        <li class="ultimos-artigos">Categorias: <? echo $inicial_acervo[0]->total_categorias; ?></li>
        <li class="ultimos-artigos">SubCategorias: <? echo $inicial_acervo[0]->total_subcategorias; ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Porém no `css` ela sobrepõe uma a outra, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como solucionar esta questão?

Este é o `css`:

```
.widget {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Não foi eu quem criou a classe `.nuvem`. O que sugerem?

Comment: Cara, especifica mais o que é o teu problema... eu mesmo não entendi o que você tá perguntando exatamente.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na imagem, como sobrepoe uma div na outra.

Comment: Nuvem é uma única div ? Ou seja, as tags, e os detalhes estão na mesma div sem qualquer outra a separar ?

Comment: realmente não dá para perceber lá muito bem qual é o problema às primeiras, mas pelo que percebi, é que a partir do texto: `DADOS DE ACERVO` já é parte da segunda `div` da nuvem de tags e que é suposto estar com um distanciamento da outra `div` anterior. Se for isso, eu penso que um `.widget{display:block;}` e se necessário `width:100%;` faz o truque. Depois é adicionar um `margin-top` para adicionar-lhe um espaçamento da `div` anterior.

Comment: Aparentemente já houve uma resposta, mas o melhor é sempre separar áreas com containers diferentes, assim pode-se evitar correcções forçadas.

Comment: Se quiser postar uma resposta @Edilson seria interessante também a sua ideia.

Comment: @AndréBaill acontece que eu não estava a ver o código de marcação, porquê não sei, mas  a solução seria colocar uma propriedade `display:block;` na classe `.widgtet`, como foi referido no comentário acima. Porque elas são 2 containers diferentes com grupos diferentes, seria mais lógico e menos doloroso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
.nuvem {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: Solução perfeita, resolveu o problema! Obrigado.

Comment: Não seria melhor aplicar o "inline-block" no .widget on invés de na .nuvem? Assim todas as classes já receberiam diretamente o atributo inline e não só resolveria esse problema como evitaria futuros.

Comment: Como não tinha muita informação de css, preferi opinar apenas naquele que seria mais interessante. Podem haver outros `widget` na página que possa interferir. Já o .nuvem me pareceu ser uma classe secundária, com menos reuso.